# Microsoft outlook daylight saving issue with ical

Tags: windows, outlook, icalendar

I am having issue displaying the daylight saving in Microsoft Outlook. I tried to display this in Microsoft Outlook and it is showing 10:00am to 6:00pm instead of 9:00am to 5:00pm.

I have configured my Windows Calendar with Automatically adjust clock for Daylight saving time.

I am assuming the 9:00am to 5:00pm have the daylight saving time applied but Microsoft Outlook is adding another one hour on top of it.

Please let me know if there is anyway to solve this issue.

Thank you.

`BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:xxxxxxxx
DTSTAMP:20160307T231014Z
DESCRIPTION:30m @ 13:00
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20160308T090000
DTEND;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20160308T170000
LOCATION:10:00am - xxxxxxxx
SUMMARY:Shift: 9:00am-5:00pm - 10:00am
END:VEVENT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use the `TZID` parameter, you need to have a `VTIMEZONE` component defined, which provides the definition for the timezone you are using.  You can find these timezone definitions at http://tzurl.org/.